# what all information will be contained in the uri that will be returned from microsoft push notification service?

Tags: windows-phone-7

what all information will be contained in the uri that will be returned when a windows mobile registers to a microsoft push notification service for the first time? will this uri keep changing? should the app update this uri every time it is started?

Comment: You may want to review the MSDN documentation regarding Push Notifications : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff402537(v=vs.92).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation discovers all your question: [Receiving Push Notifications for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202940%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)

1. That URI contains some kind of unique identifier for the pair Phone+Application.
2. Your applications should register for the ChannelUriUpdated event in case the push notification URI changes.
3. Each time your application starts, you should pass the URI from your push channel to the web service that sends out the push notifications.